# Plugin logging not appearing

Tags: plugin-development, logs

I am trying to log sone info on my plugins service work like below:

```
Craft::info(
  Craft::t('mapitapi',
          'Sleeping for 1 secs ..saved funding entry: ' . $element->id . ':' . $element->title . '| lsoa:' . $element->lsoacode),
           __METHOD__
         );
```

But nothing appears in the logs. Do i need to include something in the namespace? Or??

Comment: Info + Debug logs may get filtered out based on the application's environment. What is your `ENVIRONMENT` set as, in `.env`?

Comment: thanks for reply - .env is set like 
 ENVIRONMENT=dev

Comment: Ok, checks out… hmm! You will have a few log files, depending on where this is running. In a front-end "web" request, it'll go to `web.log`, but for the queue (regardless of how it's running), it goes in `queue.log`, and (unsurprisingly) the CLI outputs to `console.log`! Make sure you're looking in the correct file, and if the volume of data is too large to scan, you can run `tail -f storage/logs/{file}.log | grep {your method or class name}`.

Comment: It was in the queue log! Doh! Thx 

Answer (score 2):

At first, I didn't internalize the substance of the log message, and assumed the logger was filtering out your statement due to the target's configured "levels."

However, considering that `sleep()` is typically avoided in user-facing web requests, it occurred to me that we're looking at some code that is in a queue job or console command.

Craft maintains a discrete log file for each context:

1. Web requests log to `storage/logs/web.log`;
2. Queue jobs (not really a "request type" per se) log to `storage/logs/queue.log`;
3. The CLI logs to `storage/logs/console.log`;

Some plugins or modules may create and log to other files, and via `app.php`, log targets can be configured to ignore or otherwise filter and redirect log statements based on the environment.

For an in-depth look at Craft's logging system, check out [Zen and the Art of Craft CMS Log File Reading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/zen-and-the-art-of-craft-cms-log-file-reading) on nystudio107.